# Showing that my function is a surjective homomorphism from $A_4$ to $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory, permutations, group-homomorphism

I need to find, and construct, a surjective homomorphism from $A_4$ to $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$. I have shown that such a homomorphism exists by finding a normal subgroup $H = \{e, (12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)\}$ of $A_4$ of order 4 which is the kernel of the homomorphism I am trying to find.

I've constructed the following function $\psi : A_4 \to \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$,
$$
\psi(H) = \{\bar{0}\}, \; \psi((123)) = \bar{1}, \; \psi((132)) = \bar{2}, \; \psi((124)) = \bar{2}, \; \psi((142)) = \bar{1}, \; \psi((134)) = \bar{1}, \; \psi((143)) = \bar{2}, \; \text{and} \; \psi((234)) = \bar{2}, \; \psi((243)) = \bar{1}.
$$
I need to show that $\psi$ is a surjective homomorphism. By construction it is surjective, so all I have to do is show that it is a homomorphism.

How would I do this?

I assume I'd need to show that $\psi(a + b) = \psi(a) + \psi(b), \; \psi(ab) = \psi(a)\psi(b)$ for all $a,b \in A_4$, but I'm not sure how to do this for permutations.

Comment: Why don't you just take $H$ generated by $(123)$? Then $H\cong \Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$. Since $H\subset A_4$, you can map via the projection homomorphism, and you obtain a surjective homomorphism $A_4\rightarrow  \Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I have to construct a surjective homomorphism as well as show that it exists. I'm answering a question sheet given to me by my lecturer, in the answers all it says is show that $\psi$ is a homomorphism. That's the part that I'm stuck on.

Comment: In groups you only have one operation, which in $A_4$ is composition of the permutations and in $\Bbb {Z/3Z}$ is addition $\bmod 3$.  The slow way is to take every pair of permutations and show, for example, that $\psi((123)\circ(132))=\overline 0$.  A faster way is to show that $\psi(ha)=\psi(a)$ for $a \in H$.  Then there are many fewer pairs to look at.

Comment: @RossMillikan Okay, so (just to clarify) I need to show that $\psi(a \circ b) = \psi(a)+\psi(b)$? But obviously taking each $a$ and $b$ case by case rather than proving it as a for all.

Comment: Yes, that is what you are trying to show.  You can take it case by case, but that is $144$ cases.  Showing that composing with an element of $H$ does not change the result of $]\psi$ can cut this down.

Comment: @RossMillikan Great, thanks so much!